# Adding a linebreak in csv inside concat()

Tags: linux, bash, csv, unix, xmlstarlet

I have an xmlstarlet command that looks like this:

```
xml sel -T-t -m /xml/path -v "concat(name,','value,',')" -n filename.xml > output.csv
```

It outputs like so

```
#output.csv
name,value,
name,value,
name,value,
```

I want it to look like

```
name,name,name,
value,value,value,
```

I have been focused on trying different combinations within concat:

```
"concat(name,'<p>'value,',')"
"concat(name,'<br />'value,',')"
"concat(name,'"<p>"'value,',')"
"concat(name,'\n'value,',')"
```

Am  I looking at the completely wrong area?

The route I ended up taking was using a macro that transposed 8 rows into columns, within excel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `concat` statement explicitly concatenates names and values. It seems what you want to do is loop over the elements twice, selecting first the names and then the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't format the output using `xml`, then below script :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
NR==FNR{if(NR!=1){array[$1]=$2;next}}
END{
for (key in array) {printf "%s,",key;valuelist=valuelist""array[key]","}
{printf "\n";print valuelist}
}' your_file_name  > temp.txt && mv temp.txt your_file_name
```

will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can process your data after the xml command:

```
unset allnames allvalues
while IFS=, read -r name value; do
   allnames+="${name},"
   allvalues+="${value},"
done < <(echo "name1,value1
name2,value2,
name3,value3" )

echo "${allnames}"
echo "${allvalues}"
```

You can not pipe it through the while loop (vars set inside the loop will got lost), so you can use it with your command like this:

```
unset allnames allvalues
while IFS=, read -r name value; do
   allnames+="${name},"
   allvalues+="${value},"
done < <(xml sel -T-t -m /xml/path -v "concat(name,','value,',')" -n filename.xml  )

echo "${allnames}" >  output.csv
echo "${allvalues}">> output.csv
```